# how to call one notebook from another in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-emr, emr-serverless

Hello I'm newbie to AWS EMR but in the past I have worked on Azure Databricks. In azure databricks I used to call one notebook from other but In AWS AMR I'm not abele to the same.

Below is the code that I have used in EMR to call other notebook. Can someone please help me on this?

%run ./testr3.ipynb

I have tried below code.
%run ./testr3.ipynb